# RealmSwift: Realm at path already opened with different schema version

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

I've recently created a new branch and attempted refactoring much of my code to give `Realm` a shot over `CoreData`. But so far I haven't had any luck getting my code to run.

First, an exception is thrown in shared_realm.cpp. The line of code that throws the error is:

```
if (realm->config().schema_version != config.schema_version && config.schema_version != ObjectStore::NotVersioned) {
   throw MismatchedConfigException("Realm at path already opened with different schema version.");
}
```

If I skip over this exception, it catches on the second line of code in the following:

```
class func getAllCategories() -> Results<Category> {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let categories = realm.objects(Category)

    return categories
}
```

And throws this error message:

> fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error
>   Domain=io.realm Code=1 "Realm at path already opened with different
>   schema version." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Realm at path
>   already opened with different schema version., Error Code=1}

I am completely new to Realm, so any help is appreciated. My understanding from the documentation is that `Realm()` is the proper way to access the default database, which is fine for my purposes at the moment. At first I thought that perhaps a Realm had to be passed around, but I see from online examples that this doesn't appear to be the case.

I have cleaned, changed simulators, and even updated Xcode. I also attempted to comment this line of code back in:

```
// FIXME - enable schema comparison
/*if (realm->config().schema != config.schema) {
  throw MismatchedConfigException("Realm at path already opened with different schema");
}*/
```

to no avail. Feeling quite lost, so any direction is appreciated.

Comment: Are you using a Realm `Configuration` object anywhere to set up the default configuration for a Realm? If so, can you please post it here? Additionally, if you're doing a lot of development changes to the `Category` object, have you tried deleting the Realm file on disk and letting Realm create a new one?

Answer (score 1):

The schema version for a path can't be changed after it has been opened, so you'll need to change the schema before calling the path with `setSchemaVersion`.

```
setSchemaVersion(1, realmPath: Realm.defaultPath) { (migration, oldSchemaVersion) -> Void in
    if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
        migration.enumerate(Category.className(), { (oldObject, newObject) -> Void in
            let constant = oldObject!["constant"] as! String
            newObject!["constant"] = constant
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be running into this problem, because you changed the schema after you already built the app once (just a guess, you can confirm this by deleting the app and rebuilding it, which also clears the existing realm database.)

If that is indeed the problem, you should look into
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#migrations
which outlines the recommended way to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I added a new field as a String like this :

```
        schema.get("RealmCompany").addField("ctype", String.class);
```

When I declared it in the model class as an Integer.

I had to do :

```
        if (oldVersion == 7) {
            Log.i(TAG, "migrate: " + 7);
            schema.get("RealmCompany").removeField("ctype");
            schema.get("RealmCompany").addField("ctype", Integer.class);

        }
```